# log4j RollingFileAppender rollover after app restart

Tags: logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

I am having a RollingFileAppender with TimeBasedRollingPolicy, it does not roll over if the app is not running over midnight. How to roll over log file and gzip log file after App restart.

These are the log4j settings:

`log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${log.directory}/riskengine.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz
log4j.appender.file.file=${log.directory}/myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%11t] : %m (%C{1}) %n`